# Deriving monad bind from applicative (<*>) confusion

Tags: haskell, monads, reader

Working through the Haskell Book and my brain is breaking on the following example. I really don't know what the `flip` function is doing on line 21

```
1 class Functor f where
2   fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
3
4 class Functor f => Applicative f where
5   pure :: a -> f a
6   (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
7
8 class Applicative f => Monad f where
9   return :: a -> f a
10   (>>=) :: f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
11
12 instance Functor ((->) r) where
13   fmap = (.)
14
15 instance Applicative ((->) r) where
16   pure = const
17   f <*> a = \r -> f r (a r)
18
19 instance Monad ((->) r ) where
20   return = pure
21   ra >>= arb = flip arb <*> ra


-- flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c

-- ra >>= arb = flip arb <*> ra
```

As I understand it, flip takes a function that takes two arguments, then two individual arguments, and returns a value. In the bind example, are we passing `arb` as the `(a -> b -> c)`, then `<*>` as the `b` in flip's signature, and finally `ra` as the `a`? I can't see it.

I've tried making the types more specific to my actual example so you could rewrite `<*>` as

```
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

and I can do the same for bind

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

so even a dummy like myself can see that if we could swap `<*>` around
we could line then up like

```
(<???>) :: (r -> a) -> (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> b)
(>>=) ::   (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

but looking at the second arguments there, the first one wants an `r` as its first argument and bind wants an `a`

So somehow `flip` is the book's example is doing that for us, but I really don't understand how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `flip f = \arg1 arg2 -> f arg2 arg1` is all it takes to turn an `a -> r -> b` into an `r -> a -> b`. In Haskell, where functions are all one argument to one value (and the value is sometimes another function), that’s also equivalent to `flip f arg1 arg2 = f arg2 arg1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top-level point of confusion, I think: `flip` is modifying `arb`, not modifying `<*>` as you seem to believe. We have "modified" `<*>` to have the "right" argument order just by giving `<*>` its arguments in the opposite order we got them!

Now for the details. We have, as you noted:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

So, since we have on the left hand side written

```
ra >>= arb = ...
```

then what we have in scope is:

```
ra :: r -> a
arb :: a -> r -> b
```

(Note how the names were chosen to reflect the types!) Rewriting the type you gave for `flip`, we have

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c -- original
flip :: (a -> r -> b) -> r -> a -> b -- rename variables
```

hence:

```
flip arb :: r -> a -> b
```

Now recall the type of `(<*>)` that you wrote:

```
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

So for the first argument to `(<*>)`, we want something of type `r -> a -> b`. Hey! `flip arb` has that type! For the second argument, we want something of type `r -> a`. And we're in luck again, because `ra` has that type, so...

```
flip arb <*> ra :: r -> b
```

(As usual with infix operators, this is the application of the operator `(<*>)` the arguments `flip arb` and `ra`.) What type were we hoping to have? Well, we go back to the type of `(>>=)` now:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

After taking two arguments, this is supposed to return something of type `r -> b`. Cool, that's what we have built.

```
ra >>= arb = flip arb <*> ra
```

Comment: the fact that `flip` is only affecting `arb` and not the rest of the expression, is that because of the precedence of function application vs operators? `arb` is applied to `flip` and not `<*>` or `ra`, is this because applying the argument to flip is somehow taking precedence?

Comment: In other words, why don't we have to write `(flip arb) <*> ra`?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Reader-like monads are the only ones that can be implemented solely in terms of the applicative operators.

Comment: @ShaneUnger `(flip arb) <*> ra` is fine, too. And yes, prefix function application binds tighter than infix function application, so even without the parentheses it means that same thing.